# How to connect Android App to SQL Server database

Tags: android, asp.net, sql, sql-server, web-services

I am working on a project in which I am trying to have an Android app access a SQL server database. The web-portion uses an ASP.NET back end. I have seen several posts about the same or similar topics, but all of them I have found are over a year old. Has anything changed in terms of libraries, or do I still need to work on creating a web service? That seemed to be the most popular answer in all of the responses. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do not expose your database to the public. Expose a web service which will access your database.

Comment: Thanks to the ones who said this was "off-topic". Just to clarify, I wasn't asking for code, I was simply asking for a recommendation as to what to create. *sarcasm* Wow, I love this site!

Comment: I know this is a old question, but here is a way:
http://mob-programming.blogspot.com/search/label/How%20to%20connect%20and%20access%20SQL%20Database%20server%20from%20Android%20app%3F%3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a web service, yes.  We have an application that does this - we have a RESTful web service that delivers XML to the application and vice versa.  The SQL server database layer communicates with the application through this HTTPS web service for logins and exchanging data results back and forth.

Something similar to this:  [Query SQL Server via REST to get XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153433/how-to-query-sql-server-via-rest-to-get-xml)