# Expose a table as a webservice in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, web-services

Versions prior to 2012 had endpoints which offered exposure of procedures as XML web services.

Does anyone know if there is a way of exposing database structures in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Actually, that feature from SQL Server 2005 was removed in the **2008** version already. The current Best Practice is to create an Entity Framework model on top of your database and expose a WCF Data Service (OData) feed to expose your database table.

Comment: as pointed out in this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153433/how-to-query-sql-server-via-rest-to-get-xml, this is a recommended solution but not so acceptable for a quick " pilot"we're looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not "quick" - but a lot safer!