# Connecting to a MS SQL 2012 using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I've built a web app using Sharepoint 2010 and was able to connect to a Sahrepoint list using REST API (ajax). THis method allowed to use a Sharepoint list as a database.

Now I am in the process of creating a web server with MSSQL. I havent dealt with MSSQL a whole lot to be honest. I know that the ideal way to access the database is via PHP but its not an option at this moment. So i'm trying to see if I can simply use jquery/javascript to get, update, create and delete records using AJAX.

Im having a hard time finding any info on this but would anyone know if MSSQL allows HTTP access liek Sharepoint's REST API?

I would imagine there might be a way to activate this function in MSSQL somehow but again, not finging a whole lot of noob guides or noob info on this. I would appreciate any input.

Comment: I afraid that you need to write REST API by yourself.

Comment: Hi jcubic, thank you for your comment. Im not quite sure I understand. Do you mean that MSSQL does not nativeley support HTTP requests so it's not possible?

Comment: I don't think that there is sql server with http server included. You need http server and write the service by yourself or find library that do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MSSQL does not natively host any RESTful APIs.  You will need to use some kind of back end/server side code to actually make the database connection and run queries/return results.

You could use PHP (which is probably not the "ideal" for working with an MS product, but would certainly work), but you could also use a host of other server side languages - Perl, Python, Java, C#, C, C++, etc. and just expose JSON/RESTful methods for jQuery to interface with.

The "ideal" currently would be to look into [oData services](http://www.odata.org/).  Most likely you'd write an oData service hosted as a WCF service or ASP.NET site in C#.

See also:

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx
- [how to query SQL Server via REST to get XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153433/how-to-query-sql-server-via-rest-to-get-xml).